# @material material-component-web Invalid tab component given as activeTab

Tags: web, material-components

firstly let my say that the mdc documentation is difficult for non-pros like me.

I'm using Elixir Phoenix and Brunch.
I import and everything is fine.

```
import {MDCTab, MDCTabFoundation} from '@material/tabs'; import
{MDCTabBar, MDCTabBarFoundation} from '@material/tabs'; import
{MDCTabBarScroller, MDCTabBarScrollerFoundation} from
'@material/tabs';
```

I manually instantiate the tab bar in a separate function that I export

```
export var Tabbable = {
  run: function(MDCTabBar, el){
    var myDynamicTabBar = window.myDynamicTabBar = new MDCTabBar(document.querySelector('#' + el));
```

Which is following the documentation like this

```
const tabBar = new MDCTabBar(document.querySelector('#my-mdc-tab-bar'));
```

but is slightly different to the documentation's use of the tab bar in their code snippet

```
var dynamicTabBar = window.dynamicTabBar = new mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar(document.querySelector('#dynamic-tab-bar'));
```

But, whenever I try to use mdc I get a 'not defined' error.  Therefore, I'm not using it :-)

Now, when the user clicks the tab bar I capture that like this:

```
myDynamicTabBar.listen('MDCTabBar:change', function ({detail: tabs}) {
  var nthChildIndex = tabs.activeTabIndex;
  updatePanel(nthChildIndex);
});
```

The subtle difference is that my myDynamicTabBar is MDCTabBar but the documentation's dynamicTabBar is mdc.tabs.MDCTabBar

My tab control works, but it throws an error only visible in the console:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid tab component given as activeTab: Tab not
>   found within this component's tab list

which is likely because I'm not using `mdc.tabs`?  The documentation notes the change event happens on the MDCTabBar.

Therefore, how do I get rid of this annoying error in the console?

And why can I not access the global mdc?  I have tried this in my Brunch file

```
globals: { mdc: "@material"}
```

But no good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm right behind you on this! I'm frustrated with the docs too :(

You answered your own question in [this Elixir thread](https://elixirforum.com/t/material-foundation/8692/5) which is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

I found the real solution in this thread https://github.com/hyperapp/hyperapp/issues/546
MDCTabBar automatically initiates its children. So initiating tabs will result in that error.
The fix is to just initiate MDCTabBar